# What's the proper method to tweak the URL in IIS or in web.config?

Tags: iis, web-config, sitefinity

I am using Sitefinity CMS, one of my website sections for my pages is showing up in the URL and it makes the URLs look not very friendly, the section name is 'Footer' and the URL looks like this:

```
http://www.domain.com/footer/press-releases/first-press-release
```

How do I change/rewrite this URL in IIS or in web.config and remove the 'footer/' only so the URL looks like:

```
http://www.domain.com/press-releases/first-press-release
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sitefinity 6.3 and above you can edit the URL structure:
http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/forums/general-discussions-/sitefinity-6-3-released

This means, that even if the page is under the Footer group page, then you can remove the /footer/ from the URL of the page.

Just edit the Title and Properties and click on Change next to the URL.

Comment: Thank you Vaselin. Unfortunately I am on 6.2 for the time being but I'm planning to upgrade to the latest version. Quick question, will the old URLs still work after you change the structure in SF? I am asking for SEO purposes, the old ones are pretty established and indexed on search enginees.

Comment: Usually, when you change the URL of a page, Sitefinity automatically sets Enable Multiple Urls for this Page to True and adds the previous URL there. 
Best is if you test - create a test page with URL = test
Save.
Then Edit the titles and properties and change the URL to test2. At this point you will NOT see the enable Multiple URL property checked, because it is done when you click Save. 
So, Save and then edit the titles and properties again - you should see the the old URL ~/test in the multiple url field.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest you take a look at the IIS module URL Rewrite

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

It would allow you to add rules allowing the 301 redirect you appear to need.

With the module installed you could add this to your web.config file:

```
   <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="PressRelease" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^first-press-release$" />
                <conditions>
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/press-releases/first-press-release" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
    </rewrite>
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan.. I'll go ahead and test this on my staging site and will keep you posted.